# Where is "/Log/" folder created for Running Logs in Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have created a windows service and writing Running logs to "/Log/" folder, Where can I find this folder.

It is not in Program Files where I installed the service.

I created the folder as per the Kyle's anser in [Folder to dump windows service log files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365666/folder-to-dump-windows-service-log-files).

CODE to Create Folder:

```
        _logFolderPath = "/Logs/";
        string fileNameAndPath = Path.Combine(_logFolderPath, fileName);
        var fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileNameAndPath + ".txt");
        //Check if txt file exits
        if (!fileInfo.Exists)
        {
            //check if its directory exits, if not create
            if (!fileInfo.Directory.Exists) fileInfo.Directory.Create();
            //create file
            FileStream fs = fileInfo.Create();
            fs.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Put the code here and we'll see

Comment: As I know service by default starts in system32 folder, so try to look at system32/Log

Comment: I'm not sure it is a good practice to write in the windows directory. I would suggest you to write either in a custom dedicated directory, or in the ProgramData folder (`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + "/My Service/Logs"`)

Comment: @Trikks Code added , its very common code to create folder.

Comment: A quick tip: you can use `Path.Combine(_logfolderPath, fileName)` to join paths, instead of your backslash management.

Comment: @Reniuz its not there in System32 folder

Comment: Do you step in if statement? Cant you debug and see fileInfo.Directory details?

Comment: @Reniuz for debugging I am using console application , there it is working fine, but i don't know if i can debug after installing it in windows service.

Comment: Yes you can you need just learn new thing - `Debug->Attach to process` :) Also as note it is not common code to create folder. `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` - this is how you could get location of your service executable.

Comment: A Windows-service has the capability to use the MS Event-Log. Perhaps you want to prefer that for Errors and Warnings?